# Get user info from Microsoft.graph in ASP.NET Webforms

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

[image]Okay I've been at this for a couple days, here is my code and the error message.
it's a simple test that lets you click a button, and should go up to the 365 and get a certain user's calendar items on the 365, or really any info from the user.  seems I can't get it to even return to me the user count but I feel like the answer has got to be something really easy. Can someone at least verify that this is the way one would write the code?

This throws the exception:

Exception of Type' Microsoft.Graph.Models.DataErrors.ODataError' was thrown

With no other information on the error really.

[![Exception of Type' Microsoft.Graph.Models.DataErrors.ODataError' was thrown ][2]][2]

ANSWER:
the permissions was my problem, I now have a new problem about getting people's calendar info but i'll post that in a new question. Stack overflow never disappoints! Below is the correct code to get user info using ASP.net web forms and microsoft graph 5

```
      protected async void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
   
            try
            {
                string ClientId1 = "bXXX4";
                string TenantId1 = "9xxx9";

                // The permission scope required for EWS access
                var ewsScopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };


                var clientSecCred = new ClientSecretCredential(TenantId1, ClientId1, "-ixxxW");

                var GraphClient1 = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecCred, ewsScopes);

                var user2 = await GraphClient1.Users["bcaxxx8"].GetAsync();

                var res = user2.DisplayName;

            }
            catch (Exception ex) 
            {

            }
}
```

Comment: Please share the `ResponseStatusCode` property of the error. But I must say, version 5 of Graph SDK is a pain to work with compared with previous versions.

Comment: ODataError has property Error of type MainError. MainError has properties Code, Target, Message and Details. As @GauravMantri mentioned version 5 is a pain for developers and many endpoints are not fully supported.

Comment: What’s the value of Code in the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my testing, not all SDK calls evaluates to correct graph API calls. That's why it throw an error without additional information. Can you alter the user call like this

```
    var users = await graphClient.Users.GetAsync();

    foreach (var user in users.Value)
        Console.WriteLine(user.DisplayName);
```

[image]

Also maybe check the access rights
[image]

Comment: the permissions was my problem, I now have a new problem about getting people's calendar info but i'll post that in a new question. Stack overflow never disappoints! Below is the correct code to get user info using ASP.net web forms and microsoft graph 5